# Let G be a finite cyclic group of order n. If d is a positive divisor of n , prove that x^d = e has exactly d distinct solutions in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

well i know that for a group to be cyclic then there must exist an element in G for example we call it g such that $G = \langle g\rangle$ and so $g^0 = e$ and $g^0 = g^n  = e$ hence ${g^{\frac{n}{d}}}^{d} = e$ but then how could i show that there are only d distinct solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show that every element of $G$ can be written in the form $x=g^{q\cdot\frac{n}d+r}$, with $0\le r<\frac{n}d$, $0\le q<d$, then show $x^d=g^{qn+rd}=e$ precisely when $r=0$.

Comment: $\forall g\in G ,g=g^{k}$ where $k\in {0,1,2,...n-1}$ So for such values of $k$  applying division algorthim with$\frac{n}{d}$ can i prove first part ?

Answer (score 2):

$G\cong \{\zeta\in\Bbb C : \zeta^n = 1\}$

by the isomorphism $g\mapsto e^{2\pi i/n}$

Then $x^k-1$ is a polynomial with **exactly** $k$ distinct roots in $\Bbb C$, hence there are exactly $k$ solutions to $x^k-1$, no matter what $k$ is. Then in order for $h^d=e$ for some $h\in G$, this means that, under the isomorphism, $h$ is a root of $x^d-1$, of which there are exactly $d$, namely $h=g^{nk/d}\leftrightarrow e^{2\pi ik/d}$ with $1\le k\le d$.